# In Tailwind CSS, how to style elements while using dangerouslySetInnerHTML in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Code:

```
function App() {
  const html = '<p>Some text <br/><span>Some text</span></p>';

  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />;
}

export default App;
```

I want to style the `<span>` element using Tailwind CSS. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Tailwind in general requires setting classes on the element you wish to apply styles to. It's not a good pattern, but you can use arbitrary variants and child selectors.

For example:

```
const App = () => {
  const html = '<p>Some text <br/><span>Some text</span>';

  return (
    <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}}
      className="[&>p>span]:text-lg"
    />
  );
}
```

Other options could include:

- Define a 'normal' css class, attach it to the wrapper and style the spans inside the class:

  ```
   // index.css
   .wrapper span { 
       color: red;
   }

   // react component
   import './index.css';
   ...
   const App = () => {
     const html = '<p>Some text <br/><span>Some text</span>';

     return (
       <div
         dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}}
         className="wrapper"
       />
     );
   }
  ```
- Avoid using dangerouslySetInnerHTML, find another way to tackle this problem entirely (if possible)
- Use a html parser (or the DOM) and either mutate the string and re-render as a string, or, render react components from the results. Here's that in vanilla javascript (out of the context of react):

  ```
   const div = document.createElement('div')
   div.innerHTML = '<p>Some text <br/><span>Some text</span>'
   div.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(span => span.classList.add('text-lg'))
   console.log(div.innerHTML) // <p>Some text <br><span class="text-lg">Some text</span></p>
  ```

Comment: thank you for your reply. The option with css is much better. I wanted to use it, but we rewrite all styles in our project with tailwind, but in some cases we leave just css

Answer (score 3):

A simpler solution may be to use the following:

```
function App() {
  const html = '<p>Some text <br/><span class="text-lg">Some text</span></p>';

  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />;
}

export default App;
```

Imp points:

- In the string, ensure to use `class` instead of `className`; otherwise, it won't work as `it is HTML and not JSX`.
- If you are importing the HTML string from some other file, e.g., `data.json`, ensure to include it in the [`content` setting of `tailwind.config.js`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation). So that, Tailwind CSS can detect and include those classes in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set same styles on all the span elements, you can use string.replaceAll method on spans, like this:

```
 const html = '<p>Some text <br/><span>Some text</span>';
html.replaceAll('<span', '<span className='text-lg')
```